# Markup and CSS styling ideas for this design

Tags: html, css

I am working on creating a portfolio page and I really like this design, but I am not sure how to go about with the markup and more specifically the CSS styling of the blue list points in front of each work entry.

EDIT: The part I am really having trouble with is the "blue dots" that appear in front of each work entry. I got the blue line in as a border-left on the ul and then thought I could make the li list-style bullets as the dots, but I have not been able to complete that.

[image]

```css
    #work {
      margin: 40px;
    }
    
    #work .job p:first-child {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    #work ul {
      margin-left: 10px;
      border-left: 3px solid #08a1db;
    }
    
    .past-experience {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
```

```html
      <section id="work">
        <h4>Work</h4>
        <ul class="past-experience">
          <li class="job">
            <div class="visual-separator"></div>
            <p>Web Development Consulting/Studies</p>
            <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure </p>
          </li>
          <li class="job">
            <div class="visual-separator"></div>
            <p>Web Development Consulting/Studies</p>
            <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure </p>
          </li>
          <li class="job">
            <div class="visual-separator"></div>
            <p>Web Development Consulting/Studies</p>
            <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure </p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
```

Comment: Make an attempt and show us what you came up with and what specifically you're having trouble with.

Comment: Sure. 1 sec, please.

Comment: Something like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwwgQE

Comment: I was just about to Edit my post saying that it doesn't have to be perfect, I just lack design skills and I can't think of anything better. But you sir, are perfect. Please submit as an answer.

Comment: Sweet, will do. Cleaned it up a little while waiting for a response :)

Comment: I'm gonna go trough the code line by line, would it be a problem if I ask you specific questions about anything I dont understand?

Comment: for sure, ask as a comment to my solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusting the paddings and margins, then using the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements to make your circles.

```css
#work {
  margin: 40px;
}

#work .job p:first-of-type {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 0 .5em;
  line-height: 1;
}

.job p {
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.job p:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
}

#work ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.past-experience {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.job {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  border-left: 3px solid #08a1db;
  padding: 0 0 0 25px;
}

.job:not(:last-child) {
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.job::after {
  width: 10px; height: 10px;
  transform: translate(calc(-50% - 1.5px),100%)
}

.job::before {
  width: 30px; height: 30px;
  opacity: .5;
  transform: translate(calc(-50% - 2px),0);
}

.job::before, .job::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px; left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #08a1db;
  
}
```

```html
<section id="work">
    <h4>Work</h4>
    <ul class="past-experience">
      <li class="job">
        <div class="visual-separator"></div>
        <p>Web Development Consulting/Studies</p>
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure </p>
      </li>
      <li class="job">
        <div class="visual-separator"></div>
        <p>Web Development Consulting/Studies</p>
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure </p>
      </li>
      <li class="job">
        <div class="visual-separator"></div>
        <p>Web Development Consulting/Studies</p>
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
```

Comment: So you are using the translate to move it -50% (which would be to the left in this case) - 2px ( to account for the middle?). Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, -50% of it's own width to center it over the border, but also need to take off half the width of the border (2px) to truly center it... though I just looked at your code again. I thought the border was 4px, so 2px would offset half the width of the border to truly center it. Adjusted that to 1.5px since your border is 3px. Now it's centered! It was a tiny bit off center and I didn't notice.

Comment: Haha its amazing how our eyes work. I didnt notice the half a pixel at all, but now that you mentioned it I can't stop staring at it :)

Comment: Also thank you for teaching me this. It seemed like such a difficult task and when I first saw your code, I felt overwhelmed. But once I started typing it and looking at it line by line its amazingly simple, which I think is a sign of a great coder.

Is it possible for you to help me with another problem which uses the clip css property?

Comment: @TodLazarov you're welcome! Thanks for the compliment. It isn't all that complicated, but someone could make it that way with a different approach :) This kind of stuff is my jam for sure. My work is traditionally building UI's for agencies. Thanks for posting your code, too. It's a requirement on SO to post code unless it's a super easy thing, and your mockup looked like a fun build... but I would probably get downvoted for building it for you. So thanks for the cool question!